# I got an error when I click on the button

Tags: javascript, html

I have this example code and the button is not clickable, I got this error when I click on it

also when open the source code I can see two buttons why?

> Uncaught ReferenceError: addText is not defined
> onclick file:///C:/Users/Dany/Desktop/javatest/index.html:1

```html
<body data-new-gr-c-s-check-loaded="8.867.0">
<div id="button"><button onclick="addText()">Add Text</button><button></button>
</div>
<div id="printData"></div>

</body>
```

**Now this is my code, and please noticed that I need the button to be inside the js not in html and thanks**

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
    let btn = '<button onclick="addText()">Add Text<button/>';
    let data = document.getElementById("printData");
    let info = document.getElementById("button");
    info.innerHTML = btn;
    
    
    function addText(){
        data.innerHTML = "Hello World!";
        
    }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title></title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" name="viewport">
  <link href="css/css.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="js/js.js">
  </script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="button"></div>
<div id="printData"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: if you add an event listener using an attribute, the function must be global, yours is not

Comment: addText is only defined within the scope of the event listener, making it undefined when it is called from the click event.

Comment: Then how can I fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this

```
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
    let btn = '<button>Add Text</button>';
    let data = document.getElementById("printData");
    let info = document.getElementById("button");
    info.innerHTML = btn;
    
    info.addEventListener("click", () => {
        data.innerHTML = "Hello World!";
        
    })
    
});
```

Comment: Thanks bro, after 3 weeks of this issue and it has been solved :), any idea why there are duplicate inputs when I open the html source ?

Comment: You have 2 `<button>`-elements because you are not closing the first one correctly. A correct closing-tag would look like this: `</button>`, with the slash at the beginning. Your browser thinks you wanted to add 2, and corrects your HTML correspondingly.

Comment: @AbderrahimSoubai-Elidrisi , any specific reason you named your function which is essentially a function-expression?

Comment: You mean lambda expression. An anonymous function changes the context, and can create closures, whereas lambdas (or arrow-functions) can't do that. Quite a useful feature once you get your head wrapped around it.

Comment: Sure, you can call it whatever you want. But please know, it's just plain wrong.

Answer (score 0):

the function must be outside of the event listener

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
    let btn = '<button onclick="addText()">Add Text<button</button>';
    let info = document.getElementById("button");
    info.innerHTML = btn;
});

function addText(){
    let data = document.getElementById("printData");
    data.innerHTML = "Hello World!";
}
```

```html
<div id="button"></div>
<div id="printData"></div>
```